# Recent edit on a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, edits

The question that was posted first had a recent change on that question based on the comments or from answers, for which I would have earlier answered. How does stackoverflow or stackexchange do justfication for my answer for the unedited question. Incidentally, I would say my answer would look too foolish to the newly updated question for a reader.

What if I am not checking my stackexchange account for a period of time (during which question modified), and my questions voted down? Is this not against the valuable resources of stackexchange?

Edit of my question based on answers.
1.If I have to change the answer based for the newly edited question, should I always have to look at the questions I answered for edits in the old question.

2.If i have to delete my answer for the newly edited question, what justification will the community give to the readers who read my answer before I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Edit
2. Delete

Those are really your only options. However, if you want to delete it, you can always post a better answer at a future time.

Answer (score 6):

Well, if your answer no longer applies, you can do 1 of 2 things

- **Edit** your answer so that it does apply
- **Delete** your answer if you can't do the above

Stackoverfow is primarily about helping people, and not about reputation games.

So long as the edit to the question doesn't actually change the question to something completely different and unrelated, It's perfectly fine.

Comment: Even if I can edit it, if someone else has given the correct answer to the updated question I typically delete.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter So. . What do you do to the person who has come and read your answer as the correct answer by some instincts and go away. Pity, he had the wrong question and the wrong answer.